SQLite-net-pcl, перенос значения из одного Table в другой
Есть 1 Table названый Car_vendor.
public class Car_vendor
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Car_Vendors { get; set;}
}

И 2 названый Cars.
public class Cars
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Car_Stat { get; set; }
    public string car_vendors { get; set; }
}


Нужно из Table<Car_vendor> перенести значение  public string
Car_Vendors { get; set;} в
Table Cars, поле public string car_vendors {
get; set; }.

Ранее не работал с данным ядром по этому прошу объяснить на пальцах как это сделать.
